# variable not changing in for loop in python

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I am trying to calculate sine series in python .

this is the code i am using :

```
import math
x=int(raw_input('X = '))
i=1
r=0
s=1
t=1
for i in range(1,13,2):
   fact=1
   for j in range(1,i+1):
       fact = fact * j
       j=j+1
       t = (s)*(math.pow(x,i)/fact) 
   r = r + t
   s=s*(-1)
   i+=2
print('sin('+str(x)+') = '+str(r))
```

It is storing the last calculated value of t in r , and not updating it (r) .
Pls tell me why is it happening this way.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you are saying, but it sounds like you just need to indent that final print statement.

Comment: Assuming your inner loop is valid syntax (the indent level of the line above is off), you don't do anything meaningful with `t` during the course of the loop, and the last value is the only one you would see or use.  Same deal with `r`.  Also, you don't need to increment your loops in that way; that's already happening by virtue of `range`.

Comment: why do you increment j in the loop?

Comment: also, i don't know if this is intentional, but you are using i as a variable outside the loop ```i=1``` and as a loop iteration value ```for i in range(...)```.  This also makes your last line ```i+=2``` do nothing.

Comment: `r` is being updated why do you say it is not?

Comment: Sorry , for the mistake in indentation , the statement of assigning `t` is in the outer loop.

Comment: Also , `r` is getting updated but it is storing the last calculated value of `t` , but it should store the sum of all calculated values of `t`.

Comment: I've updated the answer, is working now! Sorry was my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to do something like this (look the corrections in the loops):

```
import math
x=float(raw_input('X = '))
#x = math.pi/2
xx = x
i=1
r=0
s=1
t=1
fact=1
for i in range(1,13,2):
   t = s*xx/fact
   r = r + t
   s = -s
   fact = fact * (i+1) * (i+2)
   xx *= x*x
print('sin(%f) ~ %f' % (x,r))
print('sin(%f) = %f' % (x,math.sin(x)))
```

Just tried with:

1. `x = math.pi/3` and got `0.866025`
2. `x = math.pi/2` and got `1.000000`

Comment: still not working , tried it for 1.5707963(pi/2) and got -6.87963252992e-07 , which is obviouslly not the right answer .